# LOGON/LOGOFF in the view DBA_AUDIT_SESSION

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis, audit

I have a web application built by ASP.NET Web API and the database is Oracle.

When I published the site on the IIS and run it, I recognized the following:

I found many records in the view **DBA_AUDIT_SESSION** and that's records **LOGOFF/LOGON** in the order.

After that, I let the site open for a while on a tab in the Chrome Browser without any interaction from me and I found many records **LOGOFF**, then return to the tab and open a page included it, and I found new records was generated on that view but with Action **LOGON**.

My question is:

1-That's normal or my application has an issue?

I analyzed that, but maybe I was wrong:

I think when the site run using IIS, all the old sessions will be **LOGOFF**, and after the application run on the browser, new sessions will be generated, and when the application sleep "without any interaction" the session will be **LOGOFF** and after return to the application and ask for a page included it, the application will ask a data from the database using an API and that connection will register as LOGON action.

Another question:

I check the main view **DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL** and I found the Action **LOGON** come with **comment_text** explain the Authentication process, and in my case, it comes with:

> Authenticated by: DATABASE;

My question is in every **LOGON** action the port changed, why that?

Comment: Your analysis of the LOGON / LOGOFF actions sounds correct. The *client* port number will change with every connection, as client ports are chosen in sequence to ensure that every `client ip/port : server ip/port` combination is unique, allowing one client machine to have multiple DB connections. The server IP/port number (1521 by default for Oracle) is constant across all DB connections.

Answer (score 0):

Establishing a database connection is a pretty expensive operation. Ideally a web application should be using a connection pool, so that you create create pool of database sessions initially and they remain there for the life of the application. The app tier will ask for a connection from the pool as it needs to interact with the database.

So utopia is to see an initial set of LOGON records and then no LOGOFF records until your shut the application down.